# How to call a Scala function from Play html template

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to Scala/Play Framework.

Currently, I am trying to call a Scala function from my html page: test.scala.html and pass the hash parameters to the Scala function.

I added the following lines to routes:

```
GET   /hello                      controllers.Application.test
POST  /hello                      controllers.Application.hello
```

In my test.scala.html I have:

```
@params = { window.location.hash }
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.hello) {

}
```

And my hello function is defined as:

```
 def hello() = Action {
   Ok("Hello !")
 }
```

I am completely confused by the concept of routing and @ so I am not too sure which part I did right and which part I did wrong. Please point out my mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is returning an action, not content to be displayed formatted inside view (HTML), you may want to route request to this action, from a link click or a form submit, to url configured in routing (aka `/hello`).

To add a parameter you need to either add it as url query string (e.g. for a link → `/hello?p=1`), or with an input/field for a form (e.g. `<input type="text" name="p" value="1" />`).

You can use reverse routing to get URL to call configured action. For example for a form POST to `hello`: `<form action="@routes.MyController.hello()" method="POST">...`. In this case you will need to look at form mapping, to extract parameters from request.

Answer (score 0):

1) Concept of routing

The main purpose of this routing is simply to translate each incoming HTTP request to an Action in any of your Controller. By `Reverse Routing` its simply let you use the right part, `controllers.Application.hello`, in your HTML/Controller/else.

So, for your 2 URLs above, it's likely to say that if there is a request `/hello` with method `GET` then it will go to `Application` controller and `test` method. If you don't understand the role of each Routing method, please read this [documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)..

2) the magic `@` character

`@` is a character that you can use in your HTML file if you need to use the `Scala` code or variables. It's like you can combine `PHP` code in your HTML file, if you're a PHP developer.

Here is the [full-documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplates) of what you can do with this `@` character.

3) pass the hash to the controller

To this specific case the simplest way would be passing the value trough a form:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.hello) {
    @helper.inputText(myForm("username"), 'id -> "username", 'size -> 30, 'value -> 'value here' )
}
```

However, if you're a new Play developer, then I'm afraid you need to read about [Form Submission](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms) and [Form Helper](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers) in Play Framework..